# Error while running rosserial node in ROS

Tags: mobile-robot, arduino, ros, first-robotics

I have an Arduino connected to ROS through serial port. I wrote an ardiuno code to drive motors. below is my code.

```
//Library to communicate with I2C devices
    #include "Wire.h"
    #include <Messenger.h>
    //Contain definition of maximum limits of various data type
    #include <limits.h>
     //Messenger object
    Messenger Messenger_Handler = Messenger();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Motor Pin definition
    //Left Motor
    #define USE_USBCOM
    #define INA_1 7
    #define INB_1 12    
      //PWM 1 pin 
    #define PWM_1 5

    //Right Motor
    #define INA_2 11 
    #define INB_2 10

    //PWM 2 pin 
    #define PWM_2 6
    #define RESET_PIN 4

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Motor speed from PC
    //Motor left and right speed
    float motor_left_speed = 0;
    float motor_right_speed = 0;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Setup serial, motors and Reset functions
    void setup()
    {

      //Init Serial port with 115200 baud rate
      Serial.begin(57600);  

      //Setup Motors
      SetupMotors();
       SetupReset();
      //Set up Messenger 
      Messenger_Handler.attach(OnMssageCompleted);
       }
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Setup Motors() function

    void SetupMotors()
    {

     //Left motor
     pinMode(INA_1,OUTPUT);
     pinMode(INB_1,OUTPUT); 

     //Right Motor
     pinMode(INA_2,OUTPUT);
     pinMode(INB_2,OUTPUT);  

    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Setup Reset() function

    void SetupReset()

    {

      pinMode(RESET_PIN,OUTPUT);

      ///Conenect RESET Pins to the RESET pin of launchpad,its the 16th PIN
      digitalWrite(RESET_PIN,HIGH);


    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //MAIN LOOP

    void loop()
    {

        //Read from Serial port
        Read_From_Serial();


        //Update motor values with corresponding speed and send speed values through serial port
        Update_Motors();

    delay(1000);
      }
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Read from Serial Function

    void Read_From_Serial()

    {
       while(Serial.available() > 0)
        {

           int data = Serial.read();
           Messenger_Handler.process(data);

        } 

    }
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //OnMssg Complete function definition

    void OnMssageCompleted()
    {

      char reset[] = "r";
      char set_speed[] = "s";

      if(Messenger_Handler.checkString(reset))
      {


         Reset();

      }
      if(Messenger_Handler.checkString(set_speed))
      {

         //This will set the speed
         Set_Speed();
         return; 


      }
    }
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Set speed
    void Set_Speed()
    {

      motor_left_speed = Messenger_Handler.readLong();
      motor_right_speed = Messenger_Handler.readLong();


    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Reset function
    void Reset()
    {

      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(RESET_PIN,LOW);

    }
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Will update both motors
    void Update_Motors()
    {

      moveRightMotor(motor_right_speed);
      moveLeftMotor(motor_left_speed);

     }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Motor running function


    void moveRightMotor(float rightServoValue)
    {
      if (rightServoValue>0)
      {

     digitalWrite(INA_1,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(INB_1,LOW);
     analogWrite(PWM_1,rightServoValue);

      }
      else if(rightServoValue<0)
      {
     digitalWrite(INA_1,LOW);
     digitalWrite(INB_1,HIGH);
     analogWrite(PWM_1,abs(rightServoValue));

      }

      else if(rightServoValue == 0)
      {
     digitalWrite(INA_1,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(INB_1,HIGH);


      }
    }
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void moveLeftMotor(float leftServoValue)
    {
     if (leftServoValue > 0)
      {
    digitalWrite(INA_2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(INB_2,HIGH);
    analogWrite(PWM_2,leftServoValue);
      }
      else if(leftServoValue < 0)
      {
     digitalWrite(INA_2,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(INB_2,LOW);
     analogWrite(PWM_2,abs(leftServoValue));

      }
      else if(leftServoValue == 0)
      {

       digitalWrite(INA_2,HIGH);
       digitalWrite(INB_2,HIGH);

       }  

    }
```

when i load the code to arduino and start rosserial node using command

> rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

ROS throws below error

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1475949610.718804] Unable to sync with device;
>   possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro
>   rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

I have tried changing the baud rate and fixing it similar in ROS and arduino but nothing helped

Comment: I have a similar issue when using a development board instead of my development pc. At one moment, the development board worked 50% percent of the time but now it is just not working at all. The arduino is connected to the development board thourgh USB.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you take a look at Tones' answer : http://answers.ros.org/question/210875/arduino-rosserial-unable-to-sync-with-device/?answer=237868#post-id-237868

i'm using the second workaround :

- Start the serial_node with baud rate 0, exit and restart the serial node with the correct baud rate. You have to repeat this every time the error occurs.